# How to improve this array manipulation function?

Tags: c#, f#

The function takes 2 arguments: array: int[], cap: int

Members would be ranged from 0 to cap.

e.g.

```
array = [0,0,0,2,6,3,0,4,2,4,0]
cap = 6
```

The return value is a new array of same length based on these rules:

1. The function can only change values of consecutive elements which are > 0.  i.e. any where the original array has 0, the new array has 0 as well.
2. In a consecutive series of elements which are > 0, if the maximum of it equals cap, then in the new array they are changed to 1,1,...,1,cap of the same length. e.g.  0,2,6,4,0 -> 0,1,1,6,0
3. In a consecutive series of elements which are > 0, if the maximum of it is smaller than cap, then the elements in the new array are mapped to either 1 or maximum  (if the element value < maximum then 1, otherwise maximum ) . e.g.  0,2,5,5,0 -> 0,1,5,5,0

So the sample array would map to [0,0,0,1,1,6,0,4,1,4,0]

The following are my code which are implemented in both languages, it surprises me that F# takes same lines as C#.

I would like to suggestions to improve either language.

F#

```
open System

let private reorder cap (array: int[]) =
    if Array.isEmpty array then
        array
    else
        let max = array |> Array.max
        if max = cap then
            let newArray = Array.create array.Length 1
            newArray.[array.Length-1] <- cap
            newArray
        else
            array |> Array.map (fun elem -> if elem = max then max else 1)

let private getZeroes todo = 
    todo |> Seq.takeWhile (fun elem -> elem = 0)
         |> Seq.toArray

let private getNumbers todo cap =
    todo |> Seq.takeWhile (fun elem -> elem <> 0)
         |> Seq.toArray
         |> reorder cap

let GetEquivalentPermutation (array: int[], cap) =

    let rec joinParts finished todo =
        if Seq.isEmpty todo then finished |> Seq.toArray
        else
            let zeroes = getZeroes todo
            let nextTodo = todo |> Seq.skip zeroes.Length
            let numbers = getNumbers nextTodo cap
            let finalTodo = nextTodo |> Seq.skip numbers.Length
            let newFinished = Seq.append (Seq.append finished zeroes) numbers
            joinParts newFinished finalTodo

    joinParts [] array
```

C#

```
    static int[] EquivalentOutput(int cap, int[] permutation)
    {

        IEnumerable<int> right = permutation;
        List<int> equivalentLine = new List<int>();

        while (right.Any())
        {
            var leftArray = right.TakeWhile(x => x != 0).ToArray();

            List<int> leftEquivalent;
            if (leftArray.Length == 0)
            {
                leftEquivalent = new List<int>();
            }
            else if (leftArray.Length != 1)
            {
                int max = leftArray.Max();
                if (max == cap)
                {
                    leftEquivalent = leftArray.Take(leftArray.Length - 1).Select(x => 1).ToList();
                    leftEquivalent.Add(cap);
                }
                else
                {
                    leftEquivalent = leftArray.Select(x => x < max ? 1 : max).ToList();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                leftEquivalent = leftArray.ToList();
            }
            equivalentLine.AddRange(leftEquivalent);
            equivalentLine.AddRange(right.SkipWhile(x => x != 0).TakeWhile(x => x == 0));
            right = right.SkipWhile(x => x != 0).SkipWhile(x => x == 0);

        }
        return equivalentLine.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?  Are you wanting this improved in F#, C# or both?  What type of improvements are you looking for: performance, readability?

Comment: @GeneS either will do. Yes, readability or elegance or conciseness

Comment: please separate these into two questions,  either you want a review in C# or you want a review in F#, pick one

Answer (score 2):

Seems you might be overusing Linq since you are manipulating an array.  Here is an example that to me is a bit more readable (although the readability could be improved further) and it is faster.

```
private static int[] EquivalentOutput(int cap, int[] permutation)
{
    int[] copy = permutation.ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < copy.Length; i++)
    {
        if (copy[i] == 0)
            continue;

        var consecutiveElements = copy.Skip(i).TakeWhile(x => x != 0).ToArray();
        var max = consecutiveElements.Max();
        if (max == cap)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < consecutiveElements.Length - 1; j++)
                copy[i++] = 1;
            copy[i++] = cap;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < consecutiveElements.Length; j++)
                copy[i] = copy[i++] == max ? max : 1;
        }
    }
    return copy;
}
```

**Update**:
@svick pointed out that it feels a bit "weird" changing the loop variable inside the loop so I am providing an alternative which some people will consider easier to read...

```
private static int[] EquivalentOutput(int cap, int[] permutation)
{
    int[] copy = permutation.ToArray();

    int i = 0;
    while (i < copy.Length)
    {
        if (copy[i] > 0)
        {
            var consecutiveElements = copy.Skip(i).TakeWhile(x => x != 0).ToArray();
            var max = consecutiveElements.Max();
            if (max == cap)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < consecutiveElements.Length - 1; j++)
                    copy[i++] = 1;
                copy[i++] = cap;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < consecutiveElements.Length; j++)
                    copy[i] = copy[i++] == max ? max : 1;
            }
        }

        i++;
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: I think you should use cast to `int[]` instead of `as`. If you make an error, you want to get an exception, not `null`. Also, modifying the loop variable inside the loop feels weird to me.

Comment: why do u use `.Clone()` instead of `.ToArray()`

Comment: @colingfang Wasn't thinking of that.  `.ToArray()` is much better.  Changing code to reflect this.

Comment: @svick Used @colinfant suggestion so cast no longer necessary.  As far as modifying the loop variable inside the loop...It performs well and I do not think it lessens the readability much.  The `for` loop could be changed to a `while` loop if you think that improves the readability.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should separate your concerns: first split the array into groups, then process each group separately and finally combine them back into a single array.

I think doing this results in code that is easier to understand:

```
private static IEnumerable<List<int>> SplitInGroups(int[] permutation)
{
    var result = new List<int>();

    foreach (var i in permutation)
    {
        // is this a new series?
        if (result.Any() && ((result.Last() == 0) != (i == 0)))
        {
            yield return result;
            result = new List<int>();
        }
        result.Add(i);
    }

    if (result.Any())
        yield return result;
}

private static IEnumerable<int> ProcessGroup(int cap, List<int> group)
{
    // testing the first element is enough
    if (group[0] == 0)
        return group;

    int max = group.Max();
    if (max == cap)
        return Enumerable.Repeat(1, group.Count - 1).Concat(new[] { max });

    return group.Select(i => i == max ? max : 1);
}

private static int[] EquivalentOutput(int cap, int[] permutation)
{
    return SplitInGroups(permutation).SelectMany(g => ProcessGroup(cap, g)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Definitely creative (not in a bad way) but not sure I agree it is easier to understand.